# class view error "name 'context' is not defined" when passing model to template

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to access model data in a template using the view class method (that I have done before), however the "NameError: name 'context' is not defined" continues to arise.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Email

class MapView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'Map/map.html'
    email = Email.objects.all()
    context = {'email': email}

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

if I replace "context" with an empty dictionary "{}" then I can display the template, but even if i declare "context = {}" and try to return "render(request, self.template_name, context)" I still get the context is not defined error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class attributes are **not** in the scope of class methods (ie they aren't defined).  If you need to access a class attribute from within a method, you can do this via `self`:

```
class MapView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'Map/map.html'
    email = Email.objects.all()
    context = {'email': email}

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name, self.context)
```